# How to change the SHA1 value in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I have an application that was created using an online platform. I replicated the application on Android Studio and tried to upload the new app to the app store.

The upload failed due to the fact that the SHA1 key differs from the one on the app store.

**My Question:** How can I change the SHA1 in my android studio project, to match the one already on my google play

Comment: Did you add your key in the manifest ?

Comment: I've never been aware of this. Where would I have to put it in the manifest

Comment: You should use the same key to sign your  APK, and keep the package name as the old one, then you can update your APK in Google play.

Comment: The online platform used did not supply a key, only the values of the sha1 as well as other certificates

Comment: Use the same jks file of previous versions while generating release apk

Comment: you need to sign the APK with the same key used by the online platform, go and check that platform if there is a place that says Download keystore of download keys ... anything like this, because other than that you can't you will have to take the first apk down and start a new application publish process using new apk.